# What does POC mean?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary, business-language

I'm mailing with someone to purchase a product. At the end of one of the emails that I received there's a word, "**POC**". I'm struggling to find the meaning of this word and the meaning of it in the context of this sentence:

> Once you’ve gone through everything with your manager, please confirm
> exactly what you want us to monitor and the success criteria ready for
> the POC.

Could you explain what does he mean by saying POC?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/POC

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As a reminder, questions on Stack Exchange should demonstrate some initial research effort. For example, if you try to find *POC* in a dictionary or on the web, what results do you get? What do *you* think the initials might represent? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Hello choster. I always make research when I have a question on the web. I looked into the meaning of POC but none of them made much sense in the context of this sentence. So I decided to ask here.

Comment: Proof ocf concept seems to fit from my limited point of view as in testing a theory or prototyping something. Else, you could give us more context to judge by.

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who sent you the message? If it turns out that the meaning of this abbreviation can be ascertained from readily accessible sources, then the question will be closed as off-topic on this site. On the other hand, if this is some uncommon abbreviation (or it is used in some uncommon way), then the people on this site can offer various more or less reasonable guesses as to what what your correspondent meant, but these will be only guesses. The most reliable way to find out what somebody meant by something is to ask him.

Comment: Not sure what "and the success criteria ready for the POC" means. Is there a word missing? If so, please edit your question. In my (limited) experience, POC has always meant *point of contact*, but this doesn't seem to be the meaning of POC in your sentence.

Comment: There is not enough information in the example. The question lacks necessary detail. I am voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

According to [technopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/4066/proof-of-concept-poc)

> A proof of concept (POC) is a demonstration to verify that certain concepts or theories have the potential for real-world application. In a nutshell, a POC represents the evidence demonstrating that a project or product is feasible and worthy enough to justify the expenses needed to support and develop it.

> POC is therefore a prototype that is designed to determine feasibility, but does not represent deliverables. It is usually required by investors who need tangible proof that a startup and its business proposal can guarantee a healthy return on investment (ROI)."

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your reply. I've actually read this definition on Technopedia before posting here but still didn't understand the context of the word in the sentence. Here's the full email if it would help to understand the context of the word: https://i.ibb.co/T4YwsmP/mail.png

Comment: @Brick3 The sentence you quote in the question asks for criteria which will measure the success of the proof of concept: how you will consider the trial a proven success (or indeed, a failure).

Answer (score 0):

I also met this term. In my case it had the meaning Person of Contact.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. I have never seen POC to mean Person of Contact -- that's interesting! Could you provide a reference to this usage, please?

Comment: It's *point of contact* - usually followed by a name and phone number. It's from before the internet era.